# What are some methodologies for performing feature selection for simple feed-forward neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, feature-selection

In multiple linear regression there is an `F-test` which can be used to evaluate whether or not a covariate has a meaningful impact on a model. This is typically done through either a forward selection or backwards selection algorithm. Does such a meaningful process exist for neural networks as well? The only reason I ask is because working with neural nets is an inherently stochastic process, so I do not know how I should try and get accurate bounds for the `F-statistic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually try to do the following process, I don't know whether it has name or not:

- Try to find features which an expert can say what the label is without hesitating.
- Plot correlation matrix for your sample to investigate whether each feature has correlation with others or not. I do this process whenever the input features are so much. Then try to reduce the correlated features or try to apply `PCA`. Consider the point that `PCA` alone does not care about the labels, so it may find principal components that your data would be so difficult to be separated but not necessarily.

Comment: This set of notes,http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/, (and lecture 6 in the videos) describes something similar to what you were saying

Comment: @user184074 actually I guess it is a common approach.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what was suggested by @Media, you may consider adding a softmax layer to your model right above your input layer. This is a way of visualizing which features are strongly associated with each response. Of course as you say, an F-test will not really be appropriate. This is an active area of research as far as I know.

Comment: Oh wow, I just googled "neural network feature selection" and immediately ran into a bunch of papers on the subject. I guess I will start with http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.54.4570&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: True. That paper came out in 1999, though, according to Google Scholar. There may be some more up-to-date info out there. It's far more popular, AFAIK, to use regularization (e.g. l1 or l2 or elasticnet) instead of eliminating a feature entirely.

Comment: @StatsSorceress thanks for your answer, would you please provide links for works that already has used this?